# htaccess subdirectory and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a php based site with wordpress installed in a subdirectory.

The main php site has urls in the following form

```
http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/nameofpage
```

which are rewritten using htaccess so they actually access pages like so:

```
http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/index.php?pid=$1
```

This all works as needed. My problem is with the /blog subdirectory. When in the blog part of the site trying to click on a link back to the main part of the site actually directs to

```
http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/blog/nameofpage
```

instead of

```
http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/nameofpage
```

as required and I am getting a 404 error because there is nothing there. I think this must be down to my htaccess files but I can't work out how to make it so the links to the main php page take the form I want but the blog post etc stay in the /blog/nameofpage format.

I did manage to get it so /blog/nameofpage was bringing in the correct written content for the root pages but there was no styling or images and the url was still /blog/nameofpage and I would like it to be just /nameofpage if possible.

I've posted the htaccess code for the root directory and blog subdirectories below. any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

main root htaccess code: (works for the links in the root part of the site)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

htaccess code for the wordpress subdirectory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: In simple words what you trying to achieve?

Comment: When in the blog if I click on a link in the nav bar I want it to go to the correct page i.e. domain/nameofpage rather than domain/blog/nameofpage

Comment: if it helps the site is live so you can check it out. in the main area of the site if you click on one of the links in the top right nav bar you get directed to a page with content but if you click on the blog link, go to the blog and then click on one of the links in the nav bar you're directed to blog/nameofpage and are shown a 404 error

Comment: Your mistake is you have given relative urls to your link so whatever the link in address bar it will keep append (`nameofpage`). You have to modify the anchor `<a>` links to absolute urls like `http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/nameofpage` instead of just `nameofpage`

Comment: Thankyou! Just as you were writing that this had dawned on me too and I'm just in the process of changing them and testing to make sure that works. Fingers crossed. Silly mistake as I changed them from relative to absolute for the main site and forgot to do it for the blog. Thanks so much for your help and if it works I'll up vote :)